# Adding a Service to ServiceStack

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, servicestack

I am trying to add a new service to ServiceStack, but it is not being recognized, and my routes are not showing up in the metadata.

This is my service:

```
public class EventService : Service
{
    public object Post(EventRequest event_request)
    {
        return new EventResponse() {
             name = "FirstEvent"
        }
    }
}

public class EventRequest
{
    public int event_id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/event", "POST")]
public class EventResponse {
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I have even explicitly referenced the EventService in AppHost, even though they are in the same assembly. I am just adding a service to the basic service tutorial code, and my service is defined within the same namespace as the HelloService.

```
 public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
        : base("StarterTemplate ASP.NET Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly, typeof(EventService).Assembly) { }
```

I have also tried stopping and starting the IIS express service

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because you have applied your `[Route]` to the wrong class. You need to have the route defined on the request DTO not the response DTO. So you should define it this way:

```
[Route("/event", "POST")]
public class EventRequest : IReturn<EventResponse>
{
    public int event_id { get; set; }
}
```

Your action method should define the return type too, rather than type `object`:

```
public class EventService : Service
{
    public EventResponse Post(EventRequest event_request)
    {
        return new EventResponse() {
             name = "FirstEvent"
        }
    }
}
```

You aren't getting metadata defined just now because there are no methods that are using your response `EventResponse` as a request DTO. So just a really minor thing causing your issue.

---

### Old service assembly in `bin`:

Remove the `SecondWbService.dll` from your `bin`. This is an older service that is being loaded instead of `MainWebService.dll` - the one that you are actually editing and wanting to run. Because ServiceStack doesn't allow more than one AppHost, WebActivator is finding the older DLL and running it first, thus your service is hidden. After deleting that DLL, rerun the solution and it should be picked up correctly. You can confirm this by adding a breakpoint:

```
public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
    : base("StarterTemplate ASP.NET Host", typeof(HelloService).Assembly, typeof(EventService).Assembly)
{ // BREAKPOINT HERE, confirm the assembly is loaded 
}
```

The metadata and service should then work correctly.

Comment: that was a useful response, but it did not fix my issue. I have made those changes as you specify, but the 'event' route still does not show in the metadata

Comment: @Shane Is the hello service showing up in the metadata?

Comment: Yes, the service defined as: public class HelloService : Service is showing up as 'Hello' in the metadata as per the basic example. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Shane Yes. There is nothing wrong with your definition, given that you removed the Route attribute from the response DTO to the request DTO. Can you post your full code, including the HelloService?

Comment: I've uploaded the source to mediafire [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/n2jdj3xyf2rn7al/SecondWbService_so.zip) if that makes it easier

Comment: @Shane I have looked the solution and found the problem. You have an old service assembly in your `bin`. Remove this and the problem will resolve. I have updated the answer.

Comment: great! I would never have found this. I'm new to web services so this is massively appreciated

Comment: @Shane You're welcome. Good luck with your ServiceStack projects.